# how to solve targetArrayInGivenOrder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function that takes two arrays of integers (nums and index) and
returns a target array under the following rules:
Initially target array is empty.
From left to right read nums[i] and index[i], insert at index index[i] the
value nums[i] in target array.
Repeat the previous step until there are no elements to read in nums and index.

Example 1
Input: nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], index = [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]
Output: [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]

Example 2
Input: nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0], index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not match your description. According to your example, you want to insert the `nums[index[i]]` in your target array's `i`'th position.

You can do this using Javascript's `array.map` function like this -

```
const targetArray = index.map(i => nums[i]);
```

You may need to add necessary sanity checks as well depending on the contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) along with [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const numsArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0];

const indexArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0];

let outputArr = [];

numsArr.forEach((elem, index) => {
    outputArr.splice(index, 0, numsArr[indexArr[index]]);
});

console.log(outputArr);
```